# Using ROW_NUMBER() with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, window-functions

Lets say I have this query:

```
SELECT id, date, amount, cancelled
FROM transactions
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
id  date     amount   ref
1   01/2019  5.00     a
1   02/2019  10.00    b
1   06/2019  20.00    c
2   10/2019  11.00    d
```

If there are duplicate IDs, how can I get the one with the **latest date** as well as the **sum of all amounts** and a **concatenated string of all the ref fields**?  I.e:

```
id  date     amount   ref
1   06/2019  35.00    abc
2   10/2019  11.00    d
```

Here is the SQL to get distinct IDs with the max date, but I'm not sure how to aggregate the amount/ref fields

```
WITH data_with_date_sequence AS (
    SELECT
          id
        , date
        , amount
        , ref
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS seq
    FROM dbo.SomeTable
)
SELECT
      id
    , date
    , amount
    , ref
FROM data_with_date_sequence
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2017 introduces `STRING_AGG`. `SUM() OVER ()` is supported from 2012 onwards.

Comment: Oops forgot to mention, it's 2008

Comment: Have you considered upgrading? That version is no supported at all.

Comment: I was wrong anyhow; `SUM() OVER ()` was introduced in 2005 already. 2012 added windowing support (`ROWS BETWEEN`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window function` with `sum()` :

```
WITH data_with_date_sequence AS (
    SELECT id, date, amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS seq,
           SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS amount,
           STUFF(t.ref, 1, 1, '') AS ref
    FROM dbo.SomeTable st CROSS APPLY
         ( SELECT DISTINCT ','+st1.ref
           FROM SomeTable st1 
           WHERE st1.id = st.id
           FOR XML PATH('')
         ) t(Ref)
)
SELECT id, date, amount, ref
FROM data_with_date_sequence
WHERE seq = 1;
```

If you are working with latest version then you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Here is [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/71101).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the concatenated string returns only one ref field, with the first character deleted.  E.g if you expected `abc,def`, instead it's `bc`

Comment: @JanTrindal. . . That probably you removed `,` from sub-query.  I updated query version.

Comment: I didn't remove it, it's the same exact as your query.

Comment: @JanTrindal. . . No, `CONCAT()` will not work in `2008`.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, I don't see the need for window functions. Consider this aggregation query instead:

```
select 
    id, 
    max(date) date, 
    sum(amount) amount,
    string_agg(ref, '') within group (order by date) ref
from mytable
group by id
```

Note: `string_agg()` was added in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it's 2008